# Filtering MongoDB results after Elasticsearch returns document IDs

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of documents in MongoDB and a subset of those documents are indexed in Elasticsearch for search purposes. I am using custom scoring function on ES, and the indexed json is mainly used for scoring. Once I have a sorted list of documents, what I am actually interested in is getting those full documents from MongoDB (so ES is used to return a list of IDs that I will then query on MongoDB using an `{ "$in" => "_id": [...]}` filter).

The problem is, the documents indexed on Elasticsearch may not be synced correctly, and when I get a list of results from elasticsearch, there are some documents that are undesirable (for example unpublished data, etc.)

So what I would like to do, is to "filter" this list of IDs, according to conditions based on their attributes: at least 6 attributes must have a specific value, which is always the same, ie one attribute must be "non-null", the other one false, etc).  I was thinking I could achieve this using a partial index filter, but I cannot create a duplicate index using a different partial filter expression (otherwise, I would have just added another `{ _id: 1 }` index with a `partialFilterExpression: { "my_field": true, ... }` that suits me)

What would be the best way to go about it ?

Concrete scenario

Assume those docs are indexed on MongoDB, with "published" / "hidden" attributes relevant to my search action 
(I do not want to show documents that are either unpublished or hidden)

```
{ _id: "1...", "created_at": "2019-01-20", "published": true, "hidden": false}
{ _id: "2...", "created_at": "2019-02-20", "published": false, "hidden": false}
{ _id: "3...", "created_at": "2029-03-20", "published": true, "hidden": false}
{ _id: "4...", "created_at": "2029-03-20", "published": false, "hidden": false}
{ _id: "5...", "created_at": "2029-03-20", "published": false, "hidden": true}
```

When a user searches the data with our ES implementation, 
Elasticsearch runs a scoring function and returns the scores of each document
(here the example assumes only document 1-3 are retrieved)
Because of out-of-sync issues, an unpublished document (2) could be returned

```
{ _id: "1...", "score": 1}
{ _id: "2...", "score": 2}
{ _id: "3...", "score": 3}
```

Now I want to filter again this data and retrieve from mongoDB the documents which are published and not soft deleted, ie.

```
{ _id: "1...", "created_at": "2019-01-20", "published": true, "hidden": false}
{ _id: "3...", "created_at": "2029-03-20", "published": true, "hidden": false}
```

So I need a way to run queries to retrieve the documents that would exclude document 2 which should not be visible (and is out of sync with my elasticsearch results)

Is there a trick to do this maybe using a partialIndex ? Here the scenario is simple because I have just `"published": false, "hidden": true` but my conditions are actually a bit much more complex as mentionned above, and it would be a waste to retrieve all those documents and then filter them instead of only retrieving the documents filtered by just reading a "filtered index" of IDs to see if those IDs are there or not there.

Answer (score 0):

A similar kind of approach was taken by me, in my task.

I wanted to carry out some text search and display results in front of users according to the relevance of the result.

Earlier we were using simple mongo regular expression to do this, but then we decided to do the same with ElasticSearch.

However, that result is also based on other factors and attributes in my case(which are just some fields and user data).

Here is my approach, (I will explain it with a dummy example).

Consider an Article System, where a user has his own articles written, he can write more articles, if he wants he can publish those to, if not published they are in DRAFT state, if activated then article will be in ACTIVATED state, and he can read some articles provided by System owners also, Also a user can share his articles with others.

So a typical DB design will look like..

```
{
   articleType: Custom or System,
   status: DRAFT, DEACTIVATED, ACTIVATED,
   ownerId: unique id of the owner,
   sharedWith: [unique ids of shared with users],
   title: title of the article,
   articleText: text description of the article,
   tags: some tags related to article

}
```

and some other fields that are useful.

Basically, when the article is searched, we have to show result, if he is the owner of the article, or it is shared with him by some other user, or its a system article and that system article is in the ACTIVATED state, based on the text from tags, description, title fields in document.

So according to the mongo query, I exported all the necessary fields to the ElasticSeach index first.

Then I prepared the exact same query in ElasticSeach as we were doing a search with the mongo query.

i.e. my mongo query and Elasticsearch query were exactly the same.

I removed stop-words from the search text.

I performed a search on ElasticSearch only if there is a search text, otherwise, I used mongo results only.

we also have pagination implemented in here.

I created a text index on the mongo collection.

The strategy is, whenever there is an error from ElasticSeach or Cluster is down, timeout issue, I will perform text query on mongo.

When use search articles with some text, I performed a search on ElasticSeach, also with limit and skip, and fetched the _id and index of each document.

When I received the result from ElastcSeach, I converted _ids to ObjectId, I already have a mongo query, I added this _ids array(from ElasticSeach) into query,
like:

```
{$and: [{_id: {$in : _idsFromES}} , ...remaining query]}
```

I get exactly the same result from mongo also,

The results are too satisfactory and desired for me.

Also, with this I also handled, delete, insert, update of the article, the same things will change on ElasticSeach Index too.

That way they were always up to date.

I hope this helps you find the best way to carry out your task. :-)

Comment: The problem isn't really about how to do it (that I had figured) but how to do it efficiently regarding MongoDB and the way the data is indexed. What MongoDB indexes are you using when doing this ?

Comment: I have created a text index on tags, title, and description in this case.

Comment: Exporting all fields that are used in MongoDB query and forming same query in ES will give you satisfactory results?